# Angular 2/4 Material, click on list item

Tags: angular, angular-material

My target is when clicking on any row of a list/table call a function. Couldn't make it work so now I just want to click on the 1st column of each row and call the function.

The component.html is like this, using @angular/material:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">
    <md-grid-tile class="grid-box-row" ng-click="onRowClicked(item)"> {{item.id}} </md-grid-tile>
    ... ...
```

the compiled HTML is like this:

[image: Screenshot of element in element hierarchy in Chrome DevTools]

the function is in component.ts

```
private onRowClicked(item: Order) {
    this.loggerService.debug(item.id);
}
```

Everything seems good but the function is not hit when clicking.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
ng-click="onRowClicked(item)"
```

should be

```
(click)="onRowClicked(item)"
```

Check ***Template syntax*** on: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/cheatsheet.html